# Android studio doesn't recognize AndroidManifest.xml as part of project when use git

Tags: java, android, xml, git, android-studio

good day!:

The problem comes when I use the git repository, and I want edit the AndroidManifest.xml, Android Studio show this dialog:

[dialog weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn6Ox.png)

But to compile the project isn't affect, I don't understand, I add my repository files this way:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile '/git/repository/src/myproject/AndroidManifest.xml'

        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'res/assets/', 'src/main/assets/']

        res.srcDirs = ['/git/repository/src/myproject/res/']
        java.srcDirs = ['/git/repository/src/myproject/java/']
    }

    main.assets.srcDirs += '/git/repository/src/myproject/assets/'
}
```

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if AndroidManifest.xml is added in gitignore file ?

Comment: Hi, No, I don't have any .gitignore in this folder and subfolders, only in others folders and no contain any restriction about a AndroidsManifes.xml neither xml...